# ReadLine() stops the program

Tags: vb.net, file, readline, download

I have problem with ReadLine method before downloading a file.
When program starts, "Downloaading file..." text appear, but I have to click "enter" to go further because without it program stops after ReadLine. I tried Console.Read() and Console.ReadKey(), but it's all the same, it works after download but before, it stops the whole program, weird.... ;/ I want to say "Downloading File..." and when file will be downloaded, say "Your File Is Downloaded!". Thank's for reading! :) (I've changed url adress for safety reasons).

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Module AutoUpdater

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file...")
        Console.ReadLine()
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
("http://blssss.cba.pl/rogue.rar", _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\rogue.rar")
        Console.WriteLine("Your File Is Downloaded!")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `ReadLine` stops all execution ***until it receives user input***. Of course it stops, remove it if you don't want it to stop execution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the first `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: Although fixing the issue is so simple you may want to explain @Kiran what Console.ReadLine actually does :)